# Create text file using PHP and AC2

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

So I have this PHP code, as well as actionscript code. When I run the flash file, it doesn't want to write. I've been searching for hours for a solution online, it is not permissions. (note, it is not hosted on a server, it is just in a folder on my computer, could that be the issue?)

PHP

```
<?php
$fscrn = $_POST['fscrn']
$saveTO = "full=".$fscrn."&"
file_put_contents("video.txt",$saveTO)
?>
```

and Actionscript 2

```
var videoResponse = new LoadVars();
videoResponse.onLoad = function(success)
{
    if (success)
    {
        trace("successful")
    }
}
var videoVar = new LoadVars();
videoVar.fscrn = "true";
videoVar.sendAndLoad("config/video.php",videoResponse,"POST");
```

BONUS: IMAGE OF FILE STRUCTURE

Where SWF is located
https://gyazo.com/918b0d9bcdb51996089b5d45846d1fd2

Where the php is located
https://gyazo.com/e758818fe895183b003e5b0fa5741abf

Anyone know any solutions? (It DOES print "successful" when I run it though)

TL:DR > doesn't create a new text file when PHP runs

Comment: Not super familiar with AS, but are you sure this is actually hitting your php file? My first thought would be that the sendAndLoad call isn't actually hitting your web server to execute the php file. Second if you POST to your video.php is the file saved as expected?

Comment: I am new to this. How do I post to my php? Also, as I mentioned, it is not on a server, it's on my computer locally.

Comment: You will need to have a web server running locally, and load the AS through your browser. PHP can either be executed `php config/video.php` from the command line (which I don't think AS can do), or via a web server.

Comment: Does your PHP file work when you call it locally in your browser ? I hope you have semicolons (;) at the end of the lines of your PHP file, otherwise it won't even execute due to syntax errors.